# What’s the parent of a clone called?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

Let’s say X is cloned to make Y and Y is cloned to make Z. Is there a word that uniquely identifies X in relation to Y? How about identifying X in relation to Z?

Comment: You'd probably get a more precise answer over at http://biology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could go with the names used for node relationships in a directed tree. X is a parent of Y, a grandparent of Z. X and Y are both ancestors of Z. Z is a child of Y, a grandchild of X. Y and Z are both descendants of X.

Comment: How about mom or dad?

Answer (score 14):

Clone **Source**

Example 1

> [Human Cloning: Science, Ethics, and Public Policy](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QjIDZ8OLMM4C&pg=PA139&dq=%22clone%20source%22%20-photoshop%20-adobe&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vnQAUP-bFMbG0QWI-PWtBw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22clone%20source%22%20-photoshop%20-adobe&f=false)
>
> (...) Consent of the clone source: a key regulatory issue is whether the
>   **clone source** - the source of the DNA - must consent to the cloning. (...)

Example 2

> [Liberty, Identity, and Human Cloning](http://www.humancloning.org/liberty.htm)
>
> Eugenic: the meaning of the chosen genome.-A second situation
>   involving rearing a child cloned with the consent of a third party
>   clone source arises when a couple who is coitally fertile (or who
>   could reproduce noncoitally with their own gametes) prefers instead to
>   bear and rear a child who is the clone of another person.  The **clone
>   source** could be a parent or family member, a friend, or another whose
>   genes they find desirable.  Their claim is that they will have and
>   rear a child only if it is cloned from the DNA of the source they have
>   in mind.  Does their procreative liberty include the right to clone
>   and rear?

Now, if the source itself is a clone, I'd say we could refer to it as the **clone source's source**.

Note: If you're writing scifi, I'd suggest **source** and **grandsource**, but the latter I just made up.

Comment: I love "grandsource" now I'm looking for an opportunity to use that in conversation.

Comment: Would accepting this mean, with respect to clone relationships, dropping the terms "ancestor", "descendant", and "sibling"? Would you just have "clone source" and "clone"?

Answer (score 3):

I guess I don't see what is wrong with *parent*.  If I were cloning a plant, the parent plant would be the *parent* to all the clones.

When they tissue culture hostas and make clones I have seen the source plant called the *[mother plant](http://www.plantsgalore.com/care/hostas/Hosta-propagation.htm)*.

I guess you could use *donor* if you wanted to get all clinical.  Or perhaps *The Clone Daddy* if you wanted to be hip.

Comment: +1 for *parent*. *Dorland's Illustrated Medical Dictionary*'s entry for *clone*: "one or a group of genetically identical cells, organisms, or plants derived by vegetative reproduction from a single **parent.**"   (Vegetative reproduction is asexual reproduction, as opposed to sexual reproduction.)

Comment: The problem with "parent" is that it doesn't differentiate a biological descendant from a clone. In the case of a sheep, for example, those are different things.

Comment: @JLG I like the idea that clones of animals (including humans) are produced _vegetatively _. I can see no reason why that would not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think **originator** is a reasonable word for a progenitor of a clone, but it's not clear to me whether it should be the first in the line of descendants or the most direct ancestor.

Comment: I think Gabe says it best above (probably why no one else has responded?), "progenitor of a clone" I think says it best.